# Can I prevent navigation in Blazor?

Tags: navigation, blazor, single-page-application, blazor-server-side

In Blazor Server Side app, is there some javascript involved that performs the actual navigation, e.g. when user clicks a link?
I mean something like `window.history.pushState(..)`.

Is it theoretically possible to override that javascript to prevent navigation under some circumstances (when there are unsaved changed on the page, etc.)?

Comment: This post [The Blazor NavigationManager](https://kristoffer-strube.dk/post/the-blazor-navigationmanager/) by Kristoffer Strube shows how to do that - **see at the end**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since .NET 7 there is a NavigationLock in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing namespace. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing.navigationlock?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

That component will enable you to react on an internal routing event (to a routed component) and to an external event (e.g. someone types [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in the address bar).

More information and examples here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in.
You can work with onbeforeunload on the window, but it is all up to you (or a nuget library) to code that and it is not configurable these days, so you just get the standard prompt.

It is easier to just not render any navigation links while there is unsaved data in my opinion - with the exception of leaving a way to cancel editing of course.

Comment: onbeforeunload is useless in Blazor (and SPA in general), because navigation does not upload a page

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll tell my code it doesn't work after all. It's going to be sad though. Obviously that event only fires when you navigate away from the spa, but that is the most obvious place to need it

Answer (score 0):

As Mister Magoo says above there's no out-of-the-box solution.

I've developed a set of controls that I now use to do what I believe you want.  There are three articles on my personal GutHub site, a repo where you can get the code, and a demo Azure site.  you're welcome to the code on the Repo.

You can see the solution in action [here at https://cec-blazor-database.azurewebsites.net//inlinedialogeditor](https://cec-blazor-database.azurewebsites.net//inlinedialogeditor).

See:

1. [Edit State Control to manage the state of the form i.e. Clean or Dirty](https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/EditFormState.html)
2. [Validation State Control to manage validation](https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/ValidationFormState.html).  You can use any validation that conforms with the standard Blazor Form principles - I've just included it here as it's used in the demo.
3. [Inline Dialog to lock out all links/buttons not in the edit form](https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Inline-Dialog.html).

You can also use a Modal Dialog to host your edit form - there's an article on that here:

[A Modal Editor](https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Modal-Editor.html) - note that this article will be updated in the next few days.