# In Blazor webassembly ,how to display warning message on Page reload with message

Tags: .net, blazor

how to display warning message on page releoad/refresh in Blazor webassembly

Something like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGcQw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I prevent navigation in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670792/can-i-prevent-navigation-in-blazor)

Comment: That window is called 'modal' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256798/how-to-use-bootstrap-modal-in-blazor-client-app

Comment: can we have a shorter code which works well ?!